# How to display two windows in Electron app with Electron Forge and Vite

Tags: electron, vite, electron-forge

I'm building an Electron JS app using Electron Forge and Vite, and I'd like to display a second window in the application, but it isn't displaying properly. When I run `npm run start` the second window opens, but it displays the same content as the first window. When I run `npm run make` it opens the second window still, but the window is empty.

I realize there are lots of documented ways to do this, but most use web pack, or use Electron Forge without Vite.

I've done a bare bones electron forge app and just added a second window. I generated it with the following.

```bash
npm init electron-app@latest electron-forge-2-windows -- --template=vite
```

I have the following directory structure.

```
.
├── forge.config.js
├── index.html
├── modalWindow.html
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── preload.js
│   └── renderer.js
├── vite.main.config.mjs
├── vite.modal_renderer.config.mjs
├── vite.preload.config.mjs
├── vite.renderer.config.mjs
└── yarn.lock
```

forge.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-vite',
      config: {
        // `build` can specify multiple entry builds, which can be Main process, Preload scripts, Worker process, etc.
        // If you are familiar with Vite configuration, it will look really familiar.
        build: [
          {
            // `entry` is just an alias for `build.lib.entry` in the corresponding file of `config`.
            entry: 'src/main.js',
            config: 'vite.main.config.mjs',
          },
          {
            entry: 'src/preload.js',
            config: 'vite.preload.config.mjs',
          },
        ],
        renderer: [
          {
            name: 'main_window',
            config: 'vite.renderer.config.mjs',
          },
          {
            name: 'modal_window',
            config: 'vite.modal_renderer.config.mjs',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

src/main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });

  const modalWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    modal: true,
    show: false,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  });

  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
  }

  if (MODAL_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    modalWindow.loadURL(MODAL_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    modalWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MODAL_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
  }

  modalWindow.show();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

vite.main.config.mjs

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config
export default defineConfig({});
```

vite.renderer.config.mjs

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config
export default defineConfig({});
```

vite.modal_renderer.config.mjs

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        modal_window: resolve(__dirname, 'modalWindow.html'),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>
    <script type="module" src="/src/renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

modalWindow.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Modal Window</h1>
    <div>Modal</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see that in my main.js the `MODAL_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL` constant is resolving to `http://localhost:5174` which seems right, but I don't understand what ties that URL to the correct html file. I'm guessing what I did in `vite.modal_renderer.config.mjs` is supposed to do that, but clearly I did something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your setup is that a file named `modalWindow.html` will also be built as `modalWindow.html`, so your `loadURL/loadFile` calls will lead to the wrong paths being resolved.

You can do two different things to solve this:

##### First option

You move your `modalWindow.html` as `index.html` into a different directory and set that directory as `root` in your `vite.modal_window.config.js`:

```bash
mv modalWindow.html modal_window/index.html # directory is of course arbitrary
```

`vite.modal_window.config.js`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  root: resolve(__dirname, "modal_window"),
});
```

##### Second option

You configure `vite.renderer.config.js` to build both files and then `loadURL/loadFile` with the respective names:

`vite.renderer.config.js`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main_window: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        modal_window: resolve(__dirname, 'modalWindow.html'),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

`main.js`

```js
// mainWindow
if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
} else {
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
}

// modalWindow - both use the same constant now
if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
  // add file name here ................................. v 
  modalWindow.loadURL(`${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL}/modalWindow.html`); 
} else {
  // change file name here ...................................................... v 
  modalWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/modalWindow.html`));
}
```

Of the two solutions, I'd strongly recommend the first one (and would also move the main renderer files to a separate directory while at it), even if it requires more directories and config. Edit: See [@funerr's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77457849/5613727) for a step-by-step guide on how to do that.

It cleanly separates the builds from each other by treating each renderer as an isolated build without the possibility of accessing URLs outside of the renderer's directory. It also allows different configurations for each renderer, so specific options can be set for one renderer without interfering with the others.

To explain the `*_VITE_*` constants:

`*_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL` is set to the base URL of the Vite dev server started from the renderer configuration `http://localhost:<port>/<base>`, where `port` is the first free port starting from 5173 and `base` is taken from the Vite config (`/` by default). The `loadURL` call will resolve to that URL and serve the `index.html` by default, as no specific file is given

`*_VITE_NAME` is set to the renderer's name as defined in `forge.config.js`. Forge sets Vite's `build.outDir` to `.vite/renderer/<renderer.name>/` for every renderer, so the `loadFile` call as generated by `create-electron-app` will resolve to the correct renderer directory.

I hope that helps to clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I've used @TheKvist's first method using the latest vite version.

1. Create 2 different vite config files:

- `vite.mainwindow.config.ts`
- `cite.secondwindow.config.ts`

Make them look like so:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

import path from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config
export default defineConfig({
  root: path.join(__dirname, "src", "main"), // Change "main" to your folder on step 4
});
```

(Corresponds to point 4 dir structure).

2. Change `forge.config.ts` to:

```
 renderer: [
        {
          name: "main_window",
          config: "vite.mainwindow.config.ts",
        },
        {
          name: "second_window",
          config: "vite.secondwindow.config.ts",
        },
      ],
```

3. Edit `types.d.ts` to something like:

```
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL: string;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME: string;

declare const SECOND_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL: string;
declare const SECOND_WINDOW_VITE_NAME: string;
```

(Mainly to remove squiggly lines in the typescript files)

4. Create 2 folders under `./src/`

```
./src
│   index.css
│   main.ts
│   preload.ts
│   types.d.ts
│
├───second
│       index.html
│       index.tsx
│       renderer.ts
│       style.css
│
└───main
        index.html
        main.tsx
        renderer.ts
```

Make sure the renderer.ts has the correct path imports.

Live long and prosper.